# OS X 10.10.3: Apache(2.4.12) + Passenger 5.0.10 from Homebrew doesn't work

Tags: apache-http-server, homebrew, ruby-on-rails, passenger, suricata

Trying to configure Snorby(ruby app) to work with Apache/2.4.12 and Passenger 5.0.10.

-- I've successfully installed from homebrew apache and passenger.

```
brew install httpd24 passenger
```

-- Created **/etc/apache/other/passenger.conf** (as instructed in Homebrew):

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
    PassengerRoot /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/lib/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
    PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby
```

-- Enabled virtual hosts module in **/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf**:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

-- Created Virtual host in **/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf**:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerAdmin Andryuwka@localhost
        ServerName snorby.server.loc
        ServerAlias www.snorby.server.loc
        DocumentRoot /usr/local/var/www/snorby/public
        <Directory "/usr/local/var/www/snorby/public">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
                AllowOverride all
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
                #Require all granted
                Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

-- added `127.0.0.1 snorby.server.loc www.snorby.server.loc` to **/etc/hosts**

-- restarted httpd with `apachectl restart`

but when navigating www.snorby.server.loc in browser instead of running rails-driven application (Snorby login page and dashboards) getting just the files content of `/usr/local/var/www/snorby/public`:

```
Index of /

404.html
422.html
500.html
assets/
favicon.ico
favicon.png
flash/
images/
javascripts/
robots.txt
stylesheets/
```

Should be something like in this post (scroll down):https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2011/02/27/cheat-sheet-installing-snorby-2-2-with-apache2-and-suricata-with-barnyard2-on-ubuntu-10-x/

So I assume passenger doesn't work with apache properly and doesn't start the application(correct me if I'm wrong). What am I doing wrong? 
`apachectl -M | sort` gives me this(nothing with "passenger"):

```
access_compat_module (shared)
alias_module (shared)
auth_basic_module (shared)
authn_core_module (shared)
authn_file_module (shared)
authz_core_module (shared)
authz_groupfile_module (shared)
authz_host_module (shared)
authz_user_module (shared)
autoindex_module (shared)
core_module (static)
dir_module (shared)
env_module (shared)
filter_module (shared)
headers_module (shared)
http_module (static)
log_config_module (shared)
mime_module (shared)
mpm_prefork_module (static)
php5_module (shared)
reqtimeout_module (shared)
setenvif_module (shared)
so_module (static)
status_module (shared)
unixd_module (shared)
version_module (shared)
vhost_alias_module (shared)
Loaded Modules:
```

Though homebrew claims that their apache already configured for work with passenger, I'm wondering if there is any way to check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the guy from Homebrew project on github pointed me in the right direction. For some reason my **/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf** which was created with Homebrew httpd24 installation doesn't have this line: `Include /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/other/*.conf`(though homebrew claims they should have it - I think it was relatively recent change)

That's why my didn't have passenger module included when checking `apachectl -M | sort`. (*for example:* In default **/etc/apache2/httpd.conf** there is `Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf`)

So I've added `Include /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/other/*.conf` to my my **/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf** and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The PassengerRoot pointing to an .ini file doesn't appear to make sense, it's supposed to be a directory. See the documentation at https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerRoot

Comment: Changed to `PassengerRoot /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/lib/phusion_passenger/`, restarted apache - doesn't make any difference, Also tried  `PassengerRoot /usr/local/opt/passenger/` - no luck (((

Comment: Okay, but none of those directories are (within) your virtual host DocumentRoot, nor are they Alias'ed in. Try doing that.

Comment: How to do this? Well I've changed virtual host DocumentRoot to this: `DocumentRoot /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/lib/phusion_passenger/locations.ini` and it broken my virtual host so now I'm getting this in browser: `Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.`

Comment: @Andrew again, the part after DocumentRoot cannot be a file, it has to be a directory. Make them both the same directory at that?

Comment: Oh sorry it was a typo. I meant I've done this: changed virtual host DocumentRoot to this: `DocumentRoot /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/lib/phusion_passenger` and it didn't help.

Comment: And this location matches the output of `passenger-config --root` on your machine?

Comment: thanx for attempt to help but you were wrong: DocumentRoot can be not only a directory, but also a file with a list of directories like my `/usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/lib/phusion_passenger/locations.ini` So there is nothing wrong with it. I've already found the correct solution and posted it. You should have read the problem explanation more carefully and the last code block has the hint to the problem root.

Comment: DocumentRoot? You mean PassengerRoot? Either way, that contradicts with the documentation linked above.

Comment: lol Sorry, you are correct - PassengerRoot (not DocumentRoot) but again it doesn't contradict with the documentation (it's only an example there). Everything works as expected with `.../locations.ini`  the problem was because the module passenger wasn't loaded and `apachectl -M | sort` showed that. if there was an incorrect PassengerRoot it would still show the passenger module loaded.